How do I keep Windows from acting on PS4 controller inputs to Duckstation?
I'm using a Duckstation PS1 emulator, version 0.1-7675-g0c2ab8225 (dev) on a Windows 10 Desktop. In order to play, I plug in a PS4 controller and ask Duckstation to auto-configure its inputs to match.
It seems to work, and all buttons are mapped properly. But the problem is that the "real" keyboard presses that the PS4 controller maps to outside of Duckstation are taking precedence. For example, if I press my controller' R1 and Circle button, Windows translates it to pressing Alt+Space and opens Duckstation's file options. This problem doesn't occur on any other regular game that uses my PS4 controller.
How do I keep the inputs from affecting Windows while I play?
